# SQL Script to create one table from two

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, create-table

is there a way to create procedure that will automatically create one table with all structure (columns,constraints, PKs, FKs, indexes, etc.) based on 2 other tables?

For example:

Table `a`

```
id
a1 
a2
```

Table `b`

```
id 
b1
b2
b3
```

The procedure will receive 3 table names (`a` and `b` - input, `c` - output) and will create table `c` with columns `id,a1,a2,b1,b2,b3`, including all data - constraints, PKs, FKs, indexes, etc.

I've got more than 80 pairs of tables to create, so manually it'll take like forever...

Comment: Yes all the constraints and structures are themselves held in SQL tables. However the resultant code is large. A better thing to do simpler thing in my opinion would be script all the tables (using management studio) and use a text editor to combine the pairs. Then using a join between the pairs do the inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not for the purpose of inserting the data. I need to create the tables for later use.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: working on ms sql2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This script recreate DDL (columns, FK's, PK, non-clustered index's) from several tables in one. Possible it will be helpful for you -

```
 DECLARE 
          @table1_name SYSNAME
        , @table2_name SYSNAME
        , @name_for_new_table SYSNAME
        , @schema_for_new_table SYSNAME

    SELECT 
          @table1_name = 'dbo.WorkOut'
        , @table2_name = 'dbo.WorkPlace'
        , @schema_for_new_table = 'dbo' 
        , @name_for_new_table = 'TableMerge'

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    ;WITH tbl AS 
    (
        SELECT o.[object_id]
        FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name IN (@table1_name, @table2_name)
            AND o.[type] = 'U'
            AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    ),
    index_column AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              ic.[object_id]
            , ic.index_id
            , ic.is_descending_key
            , ic.is_included_column
            , c.name
        FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE ic.[object_id] IN (SELECT t.[object_id] FROM tbl t)
    ),
    fk_columns AS 
    (
         SELECT 
              k.constraint_object_id
            , cname = c.name
            , rcname = rc.name
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    )
    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @schema_for_new_table + '].[' + @name_for_new_table + ']' + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + UPPER(t.name) + 
            CASE WHEN t.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                   THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                 WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                   THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                 WHEN t.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                   THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                 WHEN t.name = 'decimal' 
                   THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                ELSE ''
            END +
            CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
            CASE WHEN c.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + c.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
            CASE WHEN c.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(c.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(c.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END + CHAR(13)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  c.name
                , c.user_type_id
                , c.max_length
                , c.[precision]
                , c.scale
                , dc.[definition]
                , ic.seed_value
                , ic.increment_value
                , c.collation_name
                , is_nullable = MIN(CAST(c.is_nullable AS TINYINT))
                , is_identity = MIN(CAST(c.is_identity AS TINYINT))     
            FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
            LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] IN (SELECT o.[object_id] FROM tbl o)
            GROUP BY 
                  c.name
                , c.user_type_id
                , c.max_length
                , c.[precision]
                , c.scale
                , dc.[definition]
                , ic.seed_value
                , ic.increment_value
                , c.collation_name
        ) c
        JOIN sys.types t WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
        + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @schema_for_new_table + '_' + @name_for_new_table + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                (SELECT STUFF((
                 SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                 FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT) 
                 JOIN sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id
                 JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                 WHERE k.[type] = 'PK'
                     AND ic.is_included_column = 0
                     AND k.parent_object_id IN (SELECT t.[object_id] FROM tbl t)
                 FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')) + ')'  + CHAR(13)), '')
        + ')' + CHAR(13)
        + ISNULL((SELECT (
            SELECT CHAR(13) +
                 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema_for_new_table + '].[' + @name_for_new_table + '] WITH' 
                + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                    THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                    ELSE ' CHECK' 
                  END + 
                  ' ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_' + @schema_for_new_table + '_' + @name_for_new_table + '_' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')' +
                  ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')'
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                    ELSE '' 
                  END
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                    ELSE '' 
                  END 
                + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema_for_new_table + '].[' + @name_for_new_table + '] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_' + @schema_for_new_table + '_' + @name_for_new_table + '_' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
            WHERE fk.parent_object_id IN (SELECT t.[object_id] FROM tbl t)
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
        + ISNULL(((SELECT
             CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_' + @schema_for_new_table + '_' + @name_for_new_table + '_' + i.name + '] ON [' + @schema_for_new_table + '].[' + @name_for_new_table + '] (' +
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                    + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                        STUFF((
                        SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                        FROM index_column c
                        WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                            AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE i.[object_id] IN (SELECT t.[object_id] FROM tbl t)
                AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                AND i.[type] = 2
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ), '')

    PRINT @SQL
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

For example, this query generate this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableMerge
(
      AbsenceCode VARCHAR(25) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , CategoryID INT NULL
    , DateOut DATETIME NOT NULL
    , DepartmentUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    , EmployeeID INT NOT NULL
    , IsMainWorkPlace BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT((1))
    , PaymentType CHAR(2) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
    , PositionID INT NOT NULL
    , TariffScaleID INT NULL
    , TeamUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
    , TimeSheetDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    , WorkHours REAL NULL
    , WorkOutID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , WorkPlaceUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    , WorkShiftCD NVARCHAR(20) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TableMerge] PRIMARY KEY (WorkOutID ASC, WorkPlaceUID ASC)
)
```

If specify this tables as source:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[WorkOut](
    [WorkOutID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeSheetDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateOut] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsMainWorkPlace] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [WorkPlaceUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TeamUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [WorkShiftCD] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [WorkHours] [real] NULL,
    [AbsenceCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [PaymentType] [char](2) NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkOut] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkOutID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE dbo.[WorkPlace](
    [WorkPlaceUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PositionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentType] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [TariffScaleID] [int] NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkPlace] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkPlaceUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You're welcome @user2279001. If this solution is fully right for you, I will be thankful, if you accept it.